# Grub does not start anymore after removing a btrfs partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, btrfs

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10. Consider the following setup:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="0dde146f-ebdc-472d-83a2-48104e23cb8f" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00061e41-01" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="ffead33a-4330-446a-9bca-760305c04453" UUID_SUB="4ce7b017-4ad1-4035-a72b-13a5e8b68c0c" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="00061e41-05" 
/dev/sdb6: UUID="b6e06d19-6faf-4db2-b598-9d83433e853a" UUID_SUB="1e705a1e-aa40-49bd-a138-243eb0435b43" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="00061e41-06" 
/dev/sdb7: UUID="7e486227-c36f-454c-ac3c-30aa61a54358" UUID_SUB="015cc2d2-2ee4-4420-83b1-22949a4ad97a" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="00061e41-07"
```

`/dev/sdb1` is the swap partition.

`/dev/sdb5` is the root partition.

`/dev/sdb6` is my home partition.

`/dev/sdb7` is my data partition.

There used to be a `/dev/sdb8` as well, which was located after `/dev/sdb7`, at the end of my hard drive. I deleted this partition using gparted, so it's not displayed here. This partition was encapsulated in one extended partition, called `/dev/sdb2`, along with the other partitions (except swap).

Since I removed `/dev/sdb8`, my system does not boot from the hard drive anymore. It loads the BIOS just fine, and it can run a USB pendrive (that's what I'm using right now, hence `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sda`), but it won't even load Grub from the hard drive.

I wonder what's happening here. A simple `grub-install /dev/sdb` didn't help, nor did [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

When I start gparted, I'm getting an error message:

```
The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
```

I think that this has something to do with my problem. I can click either <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>Ignore</kbd> here, but clicking one of them does not make any difference.

How can I make Ubuntu boot again?

Comment: I am pretty sure that gparted error is because it is looking at your USB flash stick, which you created with `dd` rather than the startup disk creator app.  You say it won't even load grub, then what *does* it do?  Finally, putting the boot repair info report in your question would be kind of helpful.

Comment: Hi, I checked with `parted` and you're probably right about the gparted error. When I boot, it passes the BIOS screen and then a message appears: `Non-System disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready`. I pasted the boot repair info report [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9554606/)

Comment: Quick update: I decided to create a btrfs partition to fill up the empty space. I then ran `boot-repair`. Now, my system boots again. Still, I'd like to know how I can remove a btrfs partition without having boot problems.

Comment: Unless the partition is where your /boot or / filesystems are, you can just remove it.  Also the point of btrfs is to combine all of your storage space, even across multiple drives, into one flexible pool managed under a single filesystem rather than partition it up into different ones.

Comment: The strange thing is, there was nog `/boot` or `/` there. Another strange thing is that replacing it with an _empty_ partition was enough to get my system bootable again.