# Is it possible to automount a partition on a dummy location?

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

There's a partition on my drive that I don't use, called `/dev/sda8`. This partition is not listed in `/etc/fstab` so it will pop up in the Unity launcher when I boot my system.

I don't want this to happen, so I usually create a directory in `/mnt`, for example `/mnt/placeholder` and then write a new entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda8 /mnt/placeholder btrfs defaults 0 0
```

I find this solution a bit dirty, though. There's now an unnecessary directory in `/mnt`. I'd much prefer something like:

```
/dev/sda8 none btrfs defaults 0 0
```

Is it possible to automount a partition on a dummy location? Ideally, it would be protected against reading/writing.

I'm aware of the fact that I can create a hidden directory in `/mnt`, but that's not the solution I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: How about just deleting the partition that you do not use?

Comment: I can't - whenever I do that, [my system does not boot anymore](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562571/grub-does-not-start-anymore-after-removing-a-btrfs-partition). Also, this would be interesting when using multiple operating systems on one computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** I do not know if it works and maybe not for [this 3-years old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081) which seems not to be fixed for Trusty. If you run 14.10 maybe you're lucky...

I should be possible to tell directly to the disk manager to hide the disk; I can't test because I have not spare partition on this PC.

Open "Disk utility" via the dash, and select the "mount option" for your partition:

[image: disk utility]

After that, you should be able to tell the system not to mount it at boot and not make it available in the graphical interface:

[image: partition mount options]

...good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. For the command-line guys here: what this actually does is it places an entry in `/etc/fstab`: `/dev/sda3 /mnt/sda3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0`. `/mnt/sda3` doesn't have to be a directory. It won't be mounted at startup anyway.