# How do I make a drive write-protected or read-only in linux?

Tags: hard-drive, read-only

I have installed Ubuntu on my machine, I have Windows on a small ssd and I would like that ssd not visible, read-only, or write-protected while I am using linux as I do not want any mistakes to mess up that drive...

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output of `df -h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an entry for this partition in  `/etc/fstab` and specify it read-only( `ro` ).
It will automatically mount your partition (unless `noauto` is specified) as read-only when you start your system.

General format of `/etc/fstab` file is:

```
file_system   mount_point   type  options     dump  pass
```

Suppose your Windows partition in  `/dev/sad1` and you want to automatically mount is on `/media/Windows` (with read-only permission)  .

- open `/etc/fstab` in gedit using     `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
- Now append following lines in it

  ```
  #Mount Windows partition as read-only
  /dev/sda1  /media/Windows   ntfs  ro,suid,dev,noexec,auto,user,async  0 0
  ```

**Note:** If you want to prevent the auto mounting of partition during boot, you can replace `auto` option with `noauto`.

For more detail, see [Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Answer (score 1):

@g_p answer should suffice most of the time.

Otherwise, you can hide you partition as shown here: https://askubuntu.com/a/562948/16395

If you want, you could even go further and completely hide the disk from the kernel (if it's a normal SATA disk), using the boot parameter `libata.force=X.XX:disable`.

You can see detailed instruction here: https://askubuntu.com/a/387261/16395 and also here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102648/how-to-tell-linux-kernel-3-0-to-completely-ignore-a-failing-disk (since 14.04 the option is in stock kernel, so you simply need to add the command-line options).